# accessing constant from within constant class file

Tags: php

```
    class Constants
    {
            public static $url1      = "http=//url1";
            public static $url2       = Constants::$url1."/abc";
    }
```

I want to access constant from with in a class but i am not able yo do it.
How can i do it ?

Comment: why don't u use `define('URL1',"http=//url1");` and `define('URL2',URL1."/abc");`?

Comment: it would make the usage of your constants easier and is actually the default constant mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a constant. This is a static property.

You also cannot use `self` as value:

```
public static $url2 = self::$url1."/abc"; // will throw error
```

You have to initialize in constructor:

```
class Constants
{
    public static $url1 = "http=//url1";
    public static $url2;

    public function __construct(){
        self::$url2 = self::$url1."/abc";
    }
}

$const = new Constants();
echo $const::$url2;
//or if the class is initialized
echo Constants::$url2;
```

The other option would be to make a static method:

```
class Constants
{
    public static $url1 = "http=//url1";        

    public static function getUrl2(){
        return self::$url1."/abc";
    }
}

echo Constants::getUrl2();
```

Comment: class Constants
        {
            public static $url1      = "http=//url1";
            public static $url2      = self::$url1 . "/abc";
        }
is giving symtax error

Comment: this is not a gd solution , u need to create object

Comment: @Sheldon check my other option

Comment: i need to access as variable only not as a function

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Constants::` you should use `self::` to access class variables. For example:

```
public static $url2 = self::$url1 . "/abc";
```

Comment: i think it should be self::

Answer (score 0):

Just see Below Codes.

From outside the class definition

```
    <?php
    class MyClass {
        const CONST_VALUE = 'A constant value';
    }

    $classname = 'MyClass';
    echo $classname::CONST_VALUE; // As of PHP 5.3.0

    echo MyClass::CONST_VALUE;
    ?>
```

From inside the class definition

```
    <?php
    class OtherClass extends MyClass
    {
        public static $my_static = 'static var';

        public static function doubleColon() {
            echo parent::CONST_VALUE . "\n";
            echo self::$my_static . "\n";
        }
    }

    $classname = 'OtherClass';
    echo $classname::doubleColon(); // As of PHP 5.3.0

    OtherClass::doubleColon();
    ?>
```